# Data structure - Algorithm Scripting

Tags: javascript, data-structures

Hi i'm currently attending JavaScript Algorithms and Data Structures Course on [freeCodeCamp](https://freecodecamp.org) i was asked in a challenge to retrun from an array A the element that appears on a Array B i have literally done most of the part but i'm still stuck need a little bit of help

here's my code

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  var arr = [];
  // Only change code below this line
  let newArr=[];
  Object.values(source).forEach(value=>{
    newArr.push(value);
  })

  for(let i=0; i<collection.length;i++){
    for(let prop in collection[i]){
        if(newArr.indexOf(collection[i][prop])>=0){
            arr.push(collection[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
  }

  // Only change code above this line
 return arr.filter(object=>Object.keys(object).length>=newArr.length);
}

console.log(whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet" }));
console.log(whatIsInAName([{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }, { "bat": 2 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 }], { "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }));
console.log(whatIsInAName([{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }, { "apple": 1 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 }], { "apple": 1, "cookie": 2 }));
console.log(whatIsInAName([{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}], {"a": 1, "b": 9999, "c": 3}));
```

that's the conditions : [image]

Comment: can you add the calls in test form?

Comment: i have just done that

Comment: why do you need a final filtering? what is the idea of using an array as intermediate result?

Comment: ok the final filtering is just to tell my code that I only need the length of the object to be longer or equal to the object with which I compare them

Comment: my code is pretty ugly i know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out the solution to my problem folks

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  var arr = [];

  // Only change code below this line

  let newArr=[];
  let arrKey=[];
  let count=0;

  for(let key in source){
    newArr.push(source[key]);
    arrKey.push(key);
  }

  for(let i=0; i<collection.length;i++){
    count=0;
    for(let prop in collection[i]){
        if(newArr.indexOf(collection[i][prop])>=0 && arrKey.indexOf(prop)>=0){
            count++;
            console.log(count);
            if(count>=newArr.length)
            {
              arr.push(collection[i]);
              break;
            }
        }
    }
  }
  // Only change code above this line
 return arr;

}
```